# We have tables called ‘Order_records’ and ‘Customers’; how to write an SQL to show ‘Customers’ table does not have same records as “Order_records”?

Tags: sql, sqlite

that's the exact question
with no other info given - hmmm

I'd write

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customers
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM   Order_records)
```

ALSO maybe:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Customers
EXCEPT
SELECT a.*
FROM @Customers a
JOIN @Order_records b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

OR ALSO:

```
SELECT <column_list>
FROM Order_records a
LEFTJOIN Customers b 
ON a.Key = b.Key 
WHERE b.Key IS NULL;
```

what do you think?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: What is DDL of the tables ?

Comment: I would just look at the columns.  The columns would be different so the records are not the same.